# hot to write in a xml file (for parse with TBXML)

Tags: iphone, download, xml-parsing

I'm trying to download an online file, save it locally and then, parse it with TBXML!

The problem is that TBXML works only with this code:

```
    TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLFile:@"data.xml"] retain];
```

For the download i'm using this code:

```
NSError *err = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *url = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url/data.xml"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *myFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

and it works!
Now i have all the data into "myFile" NSString!

For write it into a file, i'm using this (and probably here there is the problem!)

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error;
NSString *myFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.xml"];
BOOL succeed = [myTxtFile writeToFile:myFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!succeed){
NSLog(@"no");
}
```

and it works! if i do this

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@", myString);
```

it works, i see all the data from the xml!

The problem is when i call the method to parse it with TBXML

this

```
TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLFile:myString] retain];
```

crash! I think that TBXML need a local file, saved into the project directory!

How can i do this?
thank you! :)

Comment: Please post the output of the crash. Also, you'r using `myString` in two contexts here: first you read the content of a file into it to log it. Then you pass it as param to `tbxmlWithXMLFile:` but I wonder what the content of `myString` is in that case (please verify via NSLog).

Comment: doing [CODE]NSLog(@"%@", myString);[/CODE] i see all the xml-data! But when i call [CODE]tbxmlWithXMLFile:myString[/CODE] it crash without any output, exactly like you pass an non-existent file!

Comment: The debugger will still give you some output (like it crashed due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS or because a message was sent to an object that couldn't handle it).

Comment: no, no one output! nothing, really!

Comment: That's would be very strange, as the debugger always prints something like <quote>Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.</quote> in case of a crash. Or don't you start the app via Xcode ?

Comment: no no, i start the app via xcode! Better, via the console! I've tried to parse an non-existing file (like @"dsjkfhdsfjklsa.xml") and the app crashes without output... so that's the problem! with my code the file "abc.xml" isn't save... or better, isn't save in the project directory! Do you know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are also other initializers, for example, you might want to try this one:

```
 TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLString:myString];
```

where `myString` contains the raw XML string. Or better yet:

```
 TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/data.xml"];
```

which completely eliminates your need of dealing with files and paths.

See the [API documentation](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/API.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, myString contains the whole XML. You should be doing

```
 TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLFile:@"abc.xml"] retain];
```

Comment: i've tried but nothing, the app crash without any output! it's like if the file doesn't exists!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `myFile`, not `myString` as argument to `tbxmlWithXMLFile:`. But if it crashes due to a non-existing file you better reevaluate whether you really want to use that library.

Comment: nope, it crashes :( do you think that i want to do is impossible (using tbxml, of course)?